# Symfony2 Doctrine run SQL from a file in CLI

Tags: mysql, import, doctrine-orm

I can use this to execute SQL at the CLI

```
php app/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM table"
```

But how can I use the same command to exec SQL from a file? E.g.

```
php app/console doctrine:query:sql filename.sql
```

I have tried `>` and `<` in various ways and `cat` but nothing even comes close to doing what I want.

I realised I can use straight `mysql` to do this, but I wish to do it via doctrine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
php app/console doctrine:query:sql "$(< filename.sql)"
```

Comment: You nay get a "Argument list too long" error. You an then switch to `php app/console doctrine:database:import` command.

Comment: Be aware that in current Symfony the console moved to `bin/console`.

Comment: right, doctrine >2.2 `bin/console dbal:run-sql "$(< filename.sql)"`

Answer (score 15):

With a current Symfony/Doctrine version you can easily run:

`php bin/console doctrine:database:import [files]`

Comment: nice one, but can't insert multiple in one sentence: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7