# Symfony: doctrine import sql file

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to import a sql file in doctrine (last version) 
but i cannot find the right syntax.

I would like to execute a similar command line

> php bin/console doctrine:query:sql './dump.sql'

thanks in advance
Andrea.

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898189/symfony2-doctrine-run-sql-from-a-file-in-cli/35902082

Comment: ok any idea to import a dump.sql file in symfony enviroment?

Comment: HI @HugoSoltys, I tried but it doesn't work , maybe is too old

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna do it with a symfony command I think you can create your own, which take the file path as an argument and then execute it with PDO.

```
$file = $input->getArgument('sql');
$sql = \file_get_contents($file);
$pdo = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection();

$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute();
   while ($statement->nextRowset()) {}
   $pdo->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   $pdo->rollBack();
   throw $e;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it was possible with the old version i think it's possible with the new version too

Comment: Maybe with the [Doctrine DBAL Import command](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Tools/Console/Command/ImportCommand.php) ?